# Rust Visual Studio Code code completion not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, autocomplete

I'm trying to learn Rust and installed the Rust extension for VSCode.
But I'm not seeing auto-completions for any syntax.

I'd like to call `.trim()` on `String` but I get no completion for it. I read that the completion for Rust isn't great, but the Language Server should be able to recommend methods that can be called on a struct?

I also saw a tutorial where the tutor had autocompletion in VSCode but I don't know what extension he was using.

I also tried it in WSL and thought that WSL was the problem, but after also installing Gigabytes of Visual Studio Build Tools it turns out it's also not working natively on Windows.

[image]

Comment: May be related to https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/pull/6161

Comment: @MaxV well thanks I didn't use rust-analyzer before, that was the extension I was missing :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [dustypomerleau/rust-syntax issue 4](https://github.com/dustypomerleau/rust-syntax/issues/4), since Nov. 2020, the grammar is merged into [Rust Analyzer](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer), and RA's grammar overrides others when it starts.

The completion should improve, and the [`microsoft/vscode` issue 64488](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/64488) "Need a better grammar support for Rust lang" just got closed (Dec. 2020) as a result.

Comment: also, disable the other extension after installing rust analyzer, because both together lead to conflicts

Answer (score 7):

For me solution was to use Rust Analyzer extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matklad.rust-analyzer
instead of https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust

Comment: that seems to be far more accurate in its suggestions

Comment: That doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 7):

I just had the same issue despite using the [rust-analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust-analyzer) extension. Somehow, the *Cargo.toml* of my current project was not linked to [rust-analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust-analyzer)'s linked projects.

To link it, the path of the *Cargo.toml* must appear in *{project_root}/.vscode/settings.json* as an argument to **rust-analyzer.linkedProjects**. Here is how this looks like now in my case:

```
{
    "rust-analyzer.linkedProjects": [
        "./py-kernel-regression/Cargo.toml",
        "./Cargo.toml",
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers worked for me.

After a lot of trials, below is what worked. I tested it for 2weeks and then wrote it here.

- created a new workspace with only this one rust project in it.
- installed only this rust extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust-analyzer

now code completion is working in every file.

[edit1]
After a few months of usage if rust code completion is not working then...

1. close the vs code
2. go to the dir where the rust code is written
3. delete cargo.lock .vscode folders
4. open vs code > new window > and reimport the project.

Answer (score 2):

One more thing, if your file is not added to `mod.rs` VSCode will fail to recognize as a project file, and hence the autocomplete suggestions may not work.

Or in `main.rs` your module is not listed at the top:

```rust
mod file_model;
mod utils;
// add relevant module or file
```

Comment: `mod.rs` is not the only place for module declarations, but yes a missing `mod myfilename;` will cause auto-complete and other assists to not work.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's weird and noticed nobody has ever mentioned it. If you are on macOS and installed rust via homebrew, then did `rustup component add rust-analyzer`, vs code will NOT generate auto completion.

There's also a simple solution, which requires you to completely uninstall homebrew-installed rust (or `rustup`), and then install a new `rustup` from [official install guide](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install). After a `rustup component add rust-analyzer` this time, vs code starts generating auto completions and doing full-powered analysis.

By completely uninstall your previous rust setup, I mean to `rustup component remove` all components and `rm -rf "$HOME/.cargo"` and `rm -rf "$HOME/.rustup"`, or those two customized directories, and `brew rm` homebrew-installed rust.

---

Environment: macOS 14.1 (23B74) (Intel), vs code rust extension is [rust-analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust-analyzer)

Solution is verified working in above environment.